# Connection error new installation

Tags: sql-server-2017

After installing SQL Server 2017, I am getting the connection error message while to trying to connect using Management Studio, click to Cannot connect to the server to see the error message. Please anyone help me to sort this out.

Here is the error message :

> Cannot connect to .......
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Is the service started?

Comment: No, and it cannot connect to the SQL server configuration manager, I get the following error: Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have the permission or the server is unreachable.

Comment: A new installation fixed the issue. Thank you all!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new installation fixed the issue.